# starting thinking-sphinx when starting rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm using Rails 3 with thinking-sphinx and in development mode I find myself having to type:

```
  rake ts:start
  rails s
```

Is there a way to combine these because I always forget to type the first command and it's just annoying in development mode. For production I just use capistrano to start my thinking-sphinx and there's no problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create an alias in your command line then just type `sta`. Put this in your .profile/.bashrc file (depending on what system and command line you're using)

```
alias sta="rake ts:start && rails s" #start all
```

Comment: I do this I just thought there might be a rails way of doing this, like putting it in an initializer or something.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a ruby file, say `launch.rb`

```
 system "rake ts:start"
 system "rails s"
```

and execute it:

```
 ruby launch.rb
```

You can even create an executable script as explained here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Hello_world